# kafka connect distributed NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm setting up kafka s3 sink connector and everything works when I tried with connect-standalone.sh

Now I switched to connect-distributed.sh I ran into the following error:

```
WARN [Producer clientId=producer-3] Got error produce response with correlation id 40 on topic-partition connect-configs-0, retrying (2147483611 attempts le
ft). Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:637)
```

I tried to change

```
offset.storage.replication.factor=5
config.storage.replication.factor=5
status.storage.replication.factor=5
```

which is the actual number of replicas however this error does not go away.

I also tried to change all values to match the min.insync.replicas, it still does not work.

```
Topic: myTopic    PartitionCount: 12      ReplicationFactor: 5    Configs: compression.type=producer,***min.insync.replicas=2***,segment.bytes=1073741824,max.me
ssage.bytes=2097152,index.interval.bytes=4096,retention.bytes=-1,segment.index.bytes=10485760
        Topic: myTopic        Partition: 0    Leader: 43      Replicas: 43,11,9,42,10 Isr: 10,42,9,11,43
        Topic: myTopic        Partition: 1    Leader: 11      Replicas: 11,42,10,43,9 Isr: 10,42,9,11,43
        Topic: myTopic        Partition: 2    Leader: 9       Replicas: 9,42,10,43,11 Isr: 10,42,9,11,43
        Topic: myTopic        Partition: 3    Leader: 42      Replicas: 42,10,43,11,9 Isr: 10,42,9,11,43
        Topic: myTopic        Partition: 4    Leader: 10      Replicas: 10,43,11,9,42 Isr: 10,42,9,11,43
        Topic: myTopic        Partition: 5    Leader: 43      Replicas: 43,10,11,9,42 Isr: 10,42,9,11,43
        Topic: myTopic        Partition: 6    Leader: 11      Replicas: 11,43,9,42,10 Isr: 10,42,9,11,43
        Topic: myTopic        Partition: 7    Leader: 9       Replicas: 9,43,11,42,10 Isr: 10,42,9,11,43
        Topic: myTopic        Partition: 8    Leader: 42      Replicas: 42,11,9,10,43 Isr: 10,42,9,11,43
        Topic: myTopic        Partition: 9    Leader: 10      Replicas: 10,42,43,11,9 Isr: 10,42,9,11,43
        Topic: myTopic        Partition: 10   Leader: 43      Replicas: 43,11,9,42,10 Isr: 10,42,9,11,43
        Topic: myTopic        Partition: 11   Leader: 11      Replicas: 11,42,10,43,9 Isr: 10,42,9,11,43


root@9c4c4d97dcd6:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin# grep replication.factor= /plugins/worker.properties
offset.storage.replication.factor=2
config.storage.replication.factor=2
status.storage.replication.factor=2
```

Is there anything I mis-configured?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your answer / question

> left over from running connector-standalone.sh

Standalone mode does not use those 3 topics, or properties. Therefore, it would never throw this error

---

> tried to change all values to match the min.insync.replicas

Replication factor should ideally be greater than min ISR, at all times, for any topic. You can make it equal, but it's not necessary strictly to fix this error.

> match with replicationfactor on server side

Unclear what this means. If the topics already exist, Distributed Connect will simply use them, as is, not try to recreate or validate the replication config matches the actual topics

I'd recommend at least a replication factor of 3 since you have more than 2 brokers

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I simply need to recreate the following topics in kafka:

```
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets-distributed
config.storage.topic=connect-configs-distributed
status.storage.topic=connect-status-distributed
```

Please note that I added -distributed suffix.
I used to have

```
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
config.storage.topic=connect-configs
status.storage.topic=connect-status
```

which are left over from running connector-standalone.sh
These left over topics do not work with connector-distributed.

Also it needs to match with replicationfactor on server side.

```
Topic: connect-status-distributed       PartitionCount: 5       ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs: compression.type=producer,min.insync.replicas=2,cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=10
73741824,max.message.bytes=2097152,index.interval.bytes=4096,retention.bytes=-1,segment.index.bytes=10485760
        Topic: connect-status-distributed       Partition: 0    Leader: 43      Replicas: 43,11 Isr: 43,11
        Topic: connect-status-distributed       Partition: 1    Leader: 11      Replicas: 11,42 Isr: 11,42
        Topic: connect-status-distributed       Partition: 2    Leader: 9       Replicas: 9,42  Isr: 9,42
        Topic: connect-status-distributed       Partition: 3    Leader: 42      Replicas: 42,10 Isr: 42,10
        Topic: connect-status-distributed       Partition: 4    Leader: 10      Replicas: 10,43 Isr: 10,43
Topic: connect-configs-distributed      PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs: compression.type=producer,min.insync.replicas=2,cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=10
73741824,max.message.bytes=2097152,index.interval.bytes=4096,retention.bytes=-1,segment.index.bytes=10485760
        Topic: connect-configs-distributed      Partition: 0    Leader: 11      Replicas: 11,43 Isr: 11,43
```

Comment: Connect standalone doesn't use those Kafka topics, so it's not possible for them to have been left over